# Python indentation after switching to Anaconda and Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, indentation

I have some python scripts that used to work well but all of sudden they are throwing indentation errors.

If I open them in macvim, all seems to be looking well. I can get rid of an error by going to the line that causes the problem, I hit tab and backspace (zero net operation, everything looks the same as it did before, but somehow it is resolved now).

I call my scripts from within Anaconda (I used to use Canopy before) and have switched to Python 3 at the same occasion.

If I actually vizualize the script within Anaconda, I can actually see missing indentations.

But I used to use these scripts without any problem.

The script is pretty long, so I'd rather avoid having to go over each line one by one.

Is this a known problem? Anaconda? Python 3?
Best way to resolve this?

Found a similar post ([Set a Python indent in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077179/set-a-python-indent-in-anaconda)), but without solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can get rid of an error by going to the line that causes the problem, I hit tab and backspace (zero net operation, everything looks the same as it did before, but somehow it is resolved now).

It sounds like you are mixing spaces and tabs. This can confuse Python. Make the file uniform and use one or the other only.

The reason why you are getting this may be because tab is defined as a different size in the new environment. So that's why it is better to use spaces. Many text editors should be able to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks. I ran a regex command to replace all tabs by spaces, but didn't do much. Not sure why. Anyhow, it turned out that only the lowest indentation level tabs got "lost" somehow, or got counted as zero spaces. Did things by hand with some block visual mode in vim and went pretty fast after all. I'll accept this one, as I guess this is the most common explanation for this kind of problem.